# How can i crop Image like scanmaster.apk in android

Tags: android, crop

After seeing the great solution on cropping image I ask my question again for great help.
Please see  the scan Master.apk, 
I want to crop my image not in only rectangle or square format,in any shape.

Answer (score 0):

While you are calling the native activity for capturing or choosing the image from gallery. You have to pass some key value pair in intent.

Comment: Thanks for Reply can you understand me by example

Comment: I have pass value key pair but it gives a result in rectangle or square shape which i don't want

Answer (score 0):

'Intent i = new Intent();'
        'i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, IMAGE_QUALITY);'

```
    'i.setType("image/*");'
    'i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  '

    'i.putExtra("crop", "true");
    'i.putExtra("aspectX", 0);'
    'i.putExtra("aspectY", 0);'
    'i.putExtra("outputX", 400);'
    'i.putExtra("outputY", 400);'
    'i.putExtra("return-data", true);'

    'startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"Complete action using"), CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);'
```

Try this. While editing it will show the crop box as 400*400. But you can change according to choice.'

Comment: No, it gives also crop by rectangle or square by stretch middle point, I want that when I stretch the one corner not all corner adjust automatically, I want all corners point remains same, I think You don't understand what I want, If You have android download scanmaster.apk on your phone and see the cropping